# Flash Sandbox Security error just started popping up in the last day. Dead in water. error# 3769

Tags: flash, pdf, arcgis, esri

I've got a suite of Flex/AGS based apps hosted locally that have been running for years.

In the past day or so, I've been getting the following sandbox security error ONLY in IE browsers:

SecurityError: Error #3769: Security sandbox violation: Cannot send HTTP headers when using navigateToUrl().

Here is our crossdomain.xml file:  http://maps.larimer.org/crossdomain.xml

The error only occurs when you try to use our alivepdf printing process (which again has worked with no issues for years).  I realize this isn't an esri issue but I'm hoping there is some expertise on board here that could lend a hand.  As it is, all my pdf creation capabilities are dead in the water for IE until I can resolve this issue.

If you go to http://maps.larimer.org/lil and click the "pdf" button, then "create pdf", the progress bar will either just hang or you'll get the above flash error.

The pdf creation process works just fine in Firefox and works occasionally on Chrome (but chrome has a separate pdf issue not related to this).

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.  I've exhausted all my resources on this one.

Comment: UPDATE: Looks like the culprit is the newest Flash Player (13.....214).

Looking to see if I can add anything to the crossdomain.xml file to fix this. Any ideas big or small are welcome.

Also, this isn't just IE but Firefox as well. Chrome has it's own built in Flash player so it may or may not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and solved it by replacing:

```
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(MovieClip(root).main_mov.width, MovieClip(root).main_mov.height);
jpgSource.draw(MovieClip(root).main_mov);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mysite.co.uk/tools/generic/jpg_encoder_download.php?name=design.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;

navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_self"); // Use _self not _blank to prevent popup blocker
```

with:

```
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(MovieClip(root).main_mov.width, MovieClip(root).main_mov.height);
jpgSource.draw(MovieClip(root).main_mov);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest new URLRequest("http://www.mysite.co.uk/tools/generic/jpg_encoder_download.php?name=design.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;

navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_self"); // Use _self not _blank to prevent popup blocker
```

Doing this now If you are using PHP for the file output as in `jpg_encoder_download.php`, you will notice that your

```php
$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]
```

will no longer work. I replaced `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` with

```php
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

and now works perfectly as shown in the example below.

```php
// Get bytearray
$jpg = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Add headers for download dialog-box
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
echo $jpg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: `Cannot send HTTP headers when using navigateToUrl()`. Using [`navigateToUrl()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) method, [`URLRequest`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) object provided to it should not have any headers set. As you found, this is new restriction introduced in 13.0.214 version of FP probably in course of resolving one/some issues from FP [APSB14-14] security bulletin.

Comment: Many developers consider the restriction introduced in 13.0.0.214 to be too severe. It breaks many applications. A bug has been filed, you can vote for it here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3759971

Comment: There's hope. Adobe mentioned today they will relax the HTTP header rule in the next release of flash.

Answer (score 0):

I've just posted a solution that worked for me: [**Adobe Forums:** Did Flash 13.0.0.214 break navigateToUrl?](https://forums.adobe.com/message/6391632)

Basically since I don't use headers on my app I've just stripped them out.

```as
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url:String);

// Here I don't know how many headers are sent, so we remove all the headers.
while (myRequest.requestHeaders.length > 0) {
   myRequest.requestHeaders.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Adobe Flash 13.0.0.214 and maybe also in 13.0.0.0. For details refer:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3759971
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1475657